# Visual Studio Express ClickOnce - Can't Publish .NET 4.5 Offline Installer with application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to publish an application with a pre-req being .NET 4.5. I have Clicked create a setup program to install prereq components and I have selected to include .NET Framework 4.5

I have Selected download pre-req from the following location: and set a link to my server. This is the error when I try Publish it:

**To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.**

I've tried with .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.5.1, downloaded to local PC and Server and still have the same issue.

Anyone know what the go is? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you enable ‘Download prerequisites from the same location as my application’?

Comment: I didn't, I set it to download from te following location. I tried that as well but it didnt work

Comment: Visual Studio thinks you enabled it. Open your projects' Properties windows, their Publish tab, then click Prerequisites. What install location is specified?

Answer (score 2):

I usually set it to get the files from MS so this is off the top of my head but I think that if you add the redist to the solution and than Click on the "Application Files" button in the Publish tab of your project properties and make sure that the .NET 4.5 redistributable is in the list and all the properties are set properly you should be good to go...

Comment: The 4.5 redistributable doesn't seem to be in the list. but I can't see a way to add it. Where am I meant to place the file? As Each version of my application has a different folder.

Comment: Add it to your solution and it will appear in the list... You could create the folder named Prerequisites in the root of your solution and place it there along with any other prerequisites...

Comment: I've added it to my solution in various places, but it still doesnt show up. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Did you check "Show all files" check box and rebuild after adding?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the instructions in the link? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to download and place the installer in the appropriate directory then map it inside the XML (the instructions under heading **"To add an installer package for the .NET Framework 4.5"**).