# VB 2010 Express Failed to publish applications

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a problem with my VB 2010 express now. I tried to publish an application but it shows these errors:

Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
Item '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client' could not be located in 'C:\Users\user\AppDat\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1'.
Item 'Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1' could not be located in ...
Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in '...\Engine'.

Why do I see these errors? Is there a way to solve it? Thank you.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcuo6.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Express ClickOnce - Can't Publish .NET 4.5 Offline Installer with application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298331/visual-studio-express-clickonce-cant-publish-net-4-5-offline-installer-with)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an .net Framework Issue.

Try to set another .net Framework and in Visual Studio click
on Project -> Clear.